# How to stop the loop from ending too quickly?

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

My task is to create a game, where four players G1-G4 are rolling a dice. First of all, user have to write length of board (without file 0) named X. Then he writes M plus number from 1-6 for each player separately. If he wants to print current results, he writes P. When someone has X or more, he wins. I cannot use strings.
I have a problem with while loop here. Every time I try to place M+smth in the input, the game ends after the first iteration.
queue is used to manage number of times when players rolled a dice (because of breaks in iteration caused by pressing P)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    unsigned int X, queue=0, g1=0, g2=0, g3=0, g4=0;
    char input[3];
    cin >> X;
    while(g1<X && g2<X && g3<X && g4<X){
        cin >> input;
        if(input[0]=='P'){
            cout << g1 << " " << g2 << " " << g3 << " " << g4 << endl;
            continue;
        } else{
            queue++;
            switch(queue%4){
                case 1: g1=g1+(input[2]-'0');
                case 2: g2=g2+(input[2]-'0');
                case 3: g3=g3+(input[2]-'0');
                case 0: g4=g4+(input[2]-'0');
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "END OF GAME";
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to add break instruction after each "case", change switch statement to if/if else and replace input with getchar(). However, none of above worked. I also changed C-style char array to a string, but it gave the same result.

Comment: _"user have to write length of board (without file 0) named X"_  ...  _"Then he writes M plus number from 1-6 for each player separately"_ - I have a hard time understanding the rules of this game which makes it hard to understand exactly what you are doing wrong. What do you expect `cin >> input;` to do? What C++ version are you using?

Comment: And about _"I tried to add break instruction after each "case""_ - That is often the correct thing to do but since I have no clue if you want fallthroughs or not, it's hard to say.

Comment: Input is P or M[space][number 1-6].

Comment: `'M'`, `' '` plus `'1'` makes for three `char` and leaves no room for `'\0'`

Comment: `input[3]` won't fit `P 6` - there's no room for the terminating NUL character. If `P 6` is what the user types in, then your program exhibits undefined behavior by way of buffer overflow.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Unless it's C++20 or later. Then only `'P'`, `' '` and `'\0'` will be stored, so no UB but not very usable. :-)

Comment: Y’all are right. I omitted \0 as the last element in char array.

Comment: I changed it and still it doesn’t work

Comment: I expect you do need a break; after each case. With this said it looks like instead of using a debugger to step though your code line by line looking at the variables and flow after each step you are just changing random parts of your program without understanding what it's doing. The latter method wastes a lot of time and doesn't work well as code complexity increases.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have a few problems with your code involving both syntax and memory. Also, try not to add `using namespace std;` for the reasons listed [in this very commonly referred question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

To begin with, for memory, you need to be careful with your use of C-style strings. You see, when you want to have a string with, say, n characters, then you actually need to establish the char array with one more memory character so that the compiler can add the `'\0'` character to the end of it. Do some research on this if you want more details, but just remember this as a rule when dealing with C-style strings. As a result, just declare the `input` array as having size 4.

Secondly, your code posted shows that you didn't add any `break` keywords after you switch statements. You see, `switch` works in the way that once it finds a matching case, it will perform the line(s) after that until it hits a keyword `break` or `case`. If it hits break, it will exit out the switch. However, if it hits `case`, it will continue performing the lines you entered below it.

For example, using your code, if  `queue%4` was equal to 2, then you would add your input value to `g2`, `g3`, and `g4`. So, you need a `break` after each case if you want to only increment one value.

After that, I tested your code freshly edited by me, and got the correct results.
[You can get a demo here](https://onlinegdb.com/CiV7spPCr) with input:

```
7
M+2
M+4
M+6
M+3
P
M+5
```

Your New Code with Edits and Comments:

```
#include <iostream>
int main (){
    unsigned int X, queue=0, g1=0, g2=0, g3=0, g4=0;
    char input[4]; //Just simple change from 3 to 4 here to stop memory issues and correct the last character so it is your number, not some garbage value or forced '\0' character that could make the value you add (input[2] - '0') incorrect
    std::cin >> X;
    while(g1<X && g2<X && g3<X && g4<X){
        std::cin >> input;
        if(input[0]=='P'){
            std::cout << g1 << " " << g2 << " " << g3 << " " << g4 << '\n';
            continue;
        } else{
            queue++;
            switch(queue%4){
                case 1: g1=g1+(input[2]-'0'); break; // 4 breaks to stop other adding, that could potentially already make other values go over K
                case 2: g2=g2+(input[2]-'0'); break;
                case 3: g3=g3+(input[2]-'0'); break;
                case 0: g4=g4+(input[2]-'0'); break;
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout << "END OF GAME";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, try to not add:

> using namespace std;

Also, you have some problems with memory, because you have to know that at the end of an array exists an `**'\0'**`, take care of it using `std::cin;`

You have to add `break;` statements, because you want to increase only once a time a value, and after writing the imput, you add `continue;` for not killing the program after it.